# Fire button event programmatically

Tags: iphone, button, event-handling

how to fire button event programmatically ?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is one of the vaguest I've seen, but I think you want something like this:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(theMethodToBeCalled:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then your method should look like this

```
- (void)theMethodToBeCalled:(id)sender {

}
```

Comment: I am using the same code for calling the button event, but i need the event for one button fired immediately when the application loads

Comment: So you want to fire method when the application loads? Like [self doMethod];